# unitary vector space and linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimension unitary space.
Let $T$ be a **non negative** transformation from $V$ to $V$.

Assuming there exists a natural $n$ such that $T^n = I$.

Does $T = I $ ?

I have a hard time finding a counter example so I tend to believe it is true, but I also have a hard time proving it.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "non negative"?

Comment: non negative means that all the eigenvalues are non negative

Comment: Is $V$ a vector space over $\Bbb R$ or over $\Bbb C$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $T^n=I$, any eigenvalue $\lambda$ satisfies $\lambda^n=1$, and since you are assuming the eigenvalues are all non-negative real numbers, the only possible eigenvalue is 1. Since its eigenvalues are real, $T$ may be put into its Jordan form $J$ over $\mathbb{R}$, which still satisfies $J^n=I$ so it must be diagonalizable. But it only has the eigenvalue $1$ so it must be the identity.

Being unitary isn't required.

Comment: Is there a way to use this proff but wirhout using the Jordan form? We haven't covered that material yet.

Comment: Yes. You can use that $T$ is conjugate to an upper triangular matrix instead. Or if you are assuming it is a unitary matrix, you can use the spectral theorem to conclude it is diagonalizable. Since it is homework I will let you work out the rest.

Comment: $R = \begin{pmatrix} 
  1& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.  $

$R^4 = I $

Comment: Tom, your matrix doesn't have all eigenvalues real, let alone non-negative.